# Table within td tag stretches td tag

Tags: html, css

I have an table with 4 columns each having a specified width in percentage. eg. td width="25%" and the table with a width of 100%. Now the width works perfectly when no other table is inside a column, as soon as I add the following table inside the td tag with a specific width it increases the percentage automatically.

```
<td width="25%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

I then tried adding the table above to a div tag, which sorted the stretching of column problem but overflowed the div tag containing the table

```
<div style="max-width: 100px !important; ">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Is there any way so that the table inside the td tag width specified widht automatically inherits the width and does not control it? I also tried specifying the width of the table inside the column and that also did not work

Answer (score 3):

Borders and padding can cause the elements to be larger than they appear.
For example a table of `width: 100%; border-width: 1px` inside a div with `width: 100px` will actually try to fit `102px` inside because of the pixel width of the border.

For more information on this, see the [IE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)

Answer (score 0):

is it not because you have unclosed  tags?

```
    <td width="25%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <tr>
                    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

should be

```
<td width="25%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```